# issues with a global array and sending json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName('button');//return button array
        //arrays
       var entry_age = [];//age
       var entry_relation = [];//relation 
       var entry_smoker = [];//smoker

    //add button clicked
    x[0].addEventListener("click", function(){

       var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value;//pull age from box
       var relation = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0].value;//pull relation
       let smoker = document.querySelector('[name=smoker').checked;

       //check relation 
       if(relation === "")
       {
           alert("please select a realation"); 
       }

       //check to see if age < 0
       if(age < 0 || age === " ")
       {
           alert("age not applicable");
       }



       //add data to arrays
       entry_age.push(age);
       entry_relation(relation);
       entry_smoker(smoker);

       alert(entry_age[0]);

    });

    x[1].addEventListener("click", function(){
       var age = JSON.stringify(entry_age);
       alert(entry_age[1]);
       document.getElementbyClassName("debug").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(entry_relation);
       document.getElementByClass("debug").innerHTML = JSON.stringfy(entry_smoker);
});
```

I'm trying to store a value in entry age dynamically and convert that to JSON and display it in a  only thing is I can't get the data to store in the array, how do I get the array to work globally?  At this point I'm pretty sure it's my array but do y'all see anything wrong with the JSON.  For debugging purposes I used an alert with the array index and the one in the second function is coming up as unidentified  It is to return to a pre tag with the class name of debug.  You guys have really helped me out a lot with this project.

Comment: you can change like this `entry_relation.push(relation);
       entry_smoker.push(smoker);` its also array .if not working show your `markup(html)` .we help u